# Is it possible to divide the value of a Map into two types?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Notification {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String tags;
    private String notificationType;
    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "notificationType")
    @Column(name = "value")
    @CollectionTable(name = "type_attributes", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "notification_id"))
    private Map<String, Object> info;

}
```

i should to save at info by two types.
my sample is like this :

```
1. If key is A
info : {"A" : "A Value"}
2. If Key is B
info : {"B" : ["Item1", "Item2"]}
```

so i don't know how to access this problem.
Please suggest which method is good.

Comment: Make sure you provide clear description of your need.

Comment: @Jagadeesh I need only String or List<String> two types at my Map's values;

Comment: You can use `HashMap<String, String>` which is key value pair. Hence you can hold two values

Comment: Any specific reason to have the value as `String` if key is `A`? You can still have the value as `List<String>` and add the single string value to the List.

Comment: @MadhuBhat i think, it occur same json format at info's attribute : only arrays style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, a good solution for your problem can be :

```
Multimap<String, String> myMultiMap = LinkedListMultimap.create();
```

Comment: I didn't get you ??

Comment: You may edit your previous answer instead of writing another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Multimap and not Map

Comment: I tried ```MultiMap<String, String> info;``` with same anotation at above, but i got a exception : ```Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save Objects of different types as values(e.g. both are Strings), you can use an Array as value.
e.g.

```
private Map<String, Object> info;
```

Comment: i tried, but entity manager factory refuse for undefined class ```Object```

Answer (score 0):

Use json then. It would remain your data structure and easy to take the value you want.

```
private List<JsonObject> info;

or

private List<String> info; //JsonString
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use "Multimap" instead of "Map".

Comment: How can a `String` and `List<String>` be added to a multiMap as values? How will you declare this `MultiMap` object?

Comment: Multimap is just like a Map with key as string and value as a list.

Comment: How would it be different than `Map<String, List<String>>` for the OP here?

Comment: According to your logic, you will first add item in list and then add this list to your map at last. And in my case, you just simple use multimap.put("key","value1") and that's all.

Comment: How is the MultiMap declared?

Comment: Multimap<String, String> myMultimap = LinkedListMultimap.create();

Comment: Now I get it, thanks. But anyhow I'm not sure if it'll work for the OP because the OP wants the object to be persisted in DB and the entity manager recognises MultiMap or not is something which I'm not sure about.